# why i get "uniqueness constraint was violated" on error on empty table?

Tags: multi-index, table, primarykey

i defined a table but i made a mistake putting the fields in wrong order within  EOSLIB_SERIALIZE
EOSLIB_SERIALIZE( tablename,(field1)(field4)(field3)(field2));
i did some insertions with emplace after realize the mistake and setup the corrrect order (and clean the table)
EOSLIB_SERIALIZE( tablename,(field1)(field2)(field3)(field4));
i got the error "uniqueness constraint was violated "
with an empty table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delete all instances of the old database structure before you can mutate it, I believe an instance still exists in the ether despite it not showing up anymore.

If you're just on a local testnet, reset the chain otherwise wipe the deployed contract and re-deploy a fresh copy.

Comment: i follow your recomendations , and now everithing works fine, thanks a lot